# The Magento catalog price rules disappear sometimes during the day

Tags: magento, cron, catalog

My store is running on magento 1.8.1 CE.

The catalog price rules are working fine and being set every night with a cron.

But sometimes during the day the price rules disappear ... I can solve it again by pressing the set catalog rules, but i am missing a lot of conversion trough this problem.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, however I didn't do much investigation. I am running the below code from root directory everyday as a cron job and it is working fine now.

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::app('default');

$catalogRule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule');
 $catalogRule->applyAll();

Mage::app()->removeCache('catalog_rules_dirty');

?>
```

Comment: We had a problem with this code - still not solved) ... `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1412 Table definition has changed, please retry transaction ` somehow another process is accessing the table in the same time. Not sure if we can lock the table

Comment: There are a set of cronjobs we need to set with every Magento installation which I was unaware at the time of posting. Looks like setting these cronjobs will resolve this problem. Your case must be related to some admin settings and setting Magento cronjobs will resolve this. This came off the top of my head. Not tested.

Answer (score 1):

This is our solution. Default store did not exist over here on M 1.9.3.8. it is important to also reindex after the run.

```
require_once $mageFilename;

Mage::app('admin', 'store');

try{
  $catalogPriceRule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule');
  $catalogPriceRule->applyAll();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die($e);
}

Mage::app()->removeCache('catalog_rules_dirty');

$indexProcess = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price');

if ($indexProcess) { 
    $indexProcess->reindexAll(); 
    }
```